# Banshee and Rhythmbox crash when trying to connect Android device

Tags: android, rhythmbox, music, banshee

This happens with both Rythmbox and Banshee, but I'd prefer to solve the problem with Banshee, as that is the player that suits me better.

When I run Banshee, and connect my Android device using PTP, it crashes, and I can see this error at the command prompt:

```
(Banshee:13206): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 882 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:13206): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

If I try to connect Banshee by MTP, the interface freezes consistently, which is why I am using PTP.

I would like to be able to sync my music and playlists with my Android device. Is that not possible anymore? I have tried Clementine (no syncing option), Amarok (won't connect), Rhythmbox, and Banshee.

---

Requested output from `mtp-detect`:

```
$ mtp-detect

Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 2, dev 7
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
```

Comment: Because this is not an answer to your question, but a suggestion about your wish to sync music, I'm commenting: I found a way to sync on the base of two elements: 1) [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) and 2) A "MusicSync" folder where I export my selection of music (about 5 GB) to be accessible in my phone by the syncing process. I'm using GMusicBrowser on the desktop to manage my collection, there is an "export to mp3 player" function that can be configured to copy selected/filtered songs to any local folder, maybe there is a similar function on Banshee.

Answer (score 1):

Install the required mtp tools -

`sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs`

Edit the following file -

`gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

Add the following at the end and save the file -

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="VENDORID", ATTR{idProduct}=="PRODUCTID", MODE="0666"`

In your case - VENDORID=04e8 and PRODUCTID=6860.

Now, **disconnect your phone** and run -

> sudo service udev restart
>
> sudo mkdir /media/Galaxy
>
> sudo chmod a+rwx /media/Galaxy
>
> sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME fuse

Edit the following file -

`gksu gedit /etc/fuse.conf`

Add the following at the end and save the file -

`user_allow_other`

Now, **restart your computer** and run -

> echo “alias android-connect=\”mtpfs -o allow_other /media/Galaxy\”” >>
>   ~/.bashrc
>
> echo “alias android-disconnect=\”fusermount -u /media/Galaxy\”” >>
>   ~/.bashrc
>
> source ~/.bashrc

Now connect your phone and run -`android-connect`

Similarly, to disconnect, run - `android-disconnect`

These steps have been taken from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access/).

If this does not work, you could try [go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs). A tutorial is available [here](http://blog.itsbilal.com/2012/12/connect-an-android-4-0-phonetablet-to-ubuntu-the-reliable-way/).

Finally, if nothing seems to work, you could probably have a look at [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/). You can download it for your phone from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid).

**Edit -**

Try enabling USB Debugging on the phone from Developer Settings. It has solved the problem for some users.

Comment: Rhythmbox still crashes when you press the sync button

Comment: Thank you for your help. After following your instructions, when I run `android-connect`, I get [these errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9421183/). Also note, the quote marks you've got in your question should be `"`, not `”`.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative answer since I dont have your particular phone.

You are using v1.1.6 of libmtp which is not the very latest; in Vivid version 1.1.8 is available.

You could try a new version of libmtp to see if this resolves your issue - one such source is my PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this doesnt work for you, rollback using ppa-purge

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
```

Comment: Looks like too many threads are being spawned - but its not obvious why.  Please can you install the debug symbols for libmtp and rhythmbox and rerun gdb i.e. `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-dbg libmtp-dbg`

Comment: Thanks for your continued assistance. [New requested output on Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10301400/). Also note, last night I updated my phone from Android 4.4.2 to Android 5.0, but unfortunately on the Ubuntu side, the behaviour (certain MTP Errors, Banshee and Rhythmbox crashing) has remained exactly the same.

Comment: @Questioner - excellent.  That now looks like its got all the details that the rhythmbox developers can investigate with.  Looks like it is crashing in a very specific place in Rhythmbox.  Please post the new pastebin as an attachment on their bugzilla bug tracker (file against rhythmbox) - https://bugzilla.gnome.org - once it is fixed I can then backport the fix into my rhythmbox PPA and you can try to see if the fix really works with your setup.

Comment: [Bug report filed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744775). Just a question, Is there a reason for pursuing this bug with Rhythmbox instead of Banshee?

Comment: No reason - you could equally repeat the above for Banshee and file the bug report with the Banshee developers (no idea where they are).  You are likely to find that Banshee is crashing similarly because its not handling the MTP requests correctly